# Why is this UNION like a struct?

Tags: c, struct, unions

I came across some code (it's in a library from Microchip) which has a union.

All was good, until I saw it assigned values to different members of the union *right after each other*.  My immediate thought was "They are over writing the same location..."
Then I decided to do a test.  By every measure I thought I understood, this union should be one byte (8 bits).  But it's not...  it's 4 bytes.

```
#pragma pack(1)
typedef union _STATUS
{
    BYTE Val;
    struct {
        unsigned BC8 : 1;
        unsigned BC9 : 1;
        unsigned BSTALL : 1;
        unsigned DTSEN : 1; 
        unsigned INCDIS : 1;
        unsigned KEN : 1;   
        unsigned DTS : 1;   
        unsigned UOWN : 1;  
    };
    struct {
        unsigned BC8 : 1;
        unsigned BC9 : 1;
        unsigned PID0 : 1;
        unsigned PID1 : 1;
        unsigned PID2 : 1;
        unsigned PID3 : 1;
        unsigned : 1;
        unsigned UOWN : 1;
    };
    struct {
        unsigned : 2;
        unsigned PID : 4; 
        unsigned : 2;
    };
} STATUS;
void PrintIt() {
    printf("Size of UNION is %d \n", sizeof(STATUS));
}
```

It should be the largest of any member, which each member is only 8 bits.

The code that caught my eye and made me investigate this is:

```
STAT.BC9 = 0;
STAT.BC8 = 0;
STAT.Val |= byteToSend;
```

Which the third line merges into the values from the first and second.

So I wanted to test it, it's coming out as 4 bytes, not one.  I even tested it in a few different compilers (hence the #pragma usage for MS Visual C).

Each member is exactly 8 bits, and the last two struct overlap to place the PID values in the same memory location.  And yet this is 4 bytes every way I use a compiler to evaluate it.

Is there something in the behavior of adding structs to unions?

Any explanation is appreciated.

Comment: `union _STATUS` *sigh*... you'd think that by 2021, folks will have finally got used to 
 `typedef union NAME { ... } NAME;` - it is perfectly legal, convenient, and doesn't require treading on reserved identifiers.

Comment: Pretty sure having the same member defined twice in an anonymous struct in a union is UB...

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica  Wasn't my code.  And the question was about storage size, not about declaration syntax.

Comment: Which is why I posted a comment, and not an answer

Comment: Doesn’t your compiler complain about redefinitions of `BC8`, `BC9`, and `UOWN`. GCC, Clang, and MSVC give errors, so how did you test this code in “a few different compilers”?

Comment: What is BYTE ?   .

Answer (score 6):

While not explicitly specified in the C standard, bitfield will typically occupy a unit corresponding to the base type they are declared with.

In this case all of the bitfields are declared as `unsigned`.  This type is probably 4 bytes on your system so the bitfields occupy a unit of that type.

If you change the types of the fields to `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` they should take up only one byte.  Note that this assumes your compiler allows using these types for bitfields, although most do.

Answer (score 5):

C has the concept of implicit type. So `unsigned` will declare an `unsigned int`. But it gets weirder. The same goes if you only use `const` or `static`/`auto`.

```
const x = 5; // Declares a const int variable
static x;    // Declares a static int variable
const static unsigned x = 5; // Declares a const static unsigned int variable
```

What you want is an `unsigned char`.

> It should be the largest of any member, which each member is only 8 bits.

It should be *at least* that size. Nothing prevents it from being bigger.

Answer (score 1):

1. It will not compile as you have duplicate member names in anonymous structures.
2. You do need to pack it if you use 8 bits type for your bitfields.

```cpp
typedef union 
{
    unsigned char Val;
    struct {
        unsigned char BC8 : 1;
        unsigned char BC9 : 1;
        unsigned char BSTALL : 1;
        unsigned char DTSEN : 1; 
        unsigned char INCDIS : 1;
        unsigned char KEN : 1;   
        unsigned char DTS : 1;   
        unsigned char UOWN : 1;  
    };
    struct {
        unsigned char BC81 : 1;
        unsigned char BC91 : 1;
        unsigned char PID0 : 1;
        unsigned char PID1 : 1;
        unsigned char PID2 : 1;
        unsigned char PID3 : 1;
        unsigned char : 1;
        unsigned char UOWN1 : 1;
    };
    struct {
        unsigned char : 2;
        unsigned char PID : 4; 
        unsigned char : 2;
    };
} STATUS;

int main(void) {
    printf("Size of UNION is %d \n", (int)sizeof(STATUS));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/zsfhnGeWd

Remember that some compilers will pack to the type you specify (chibicc for example).

Answer (score 0):

While dbush was answering, I was adding my own answer as well, after digging deeper.

I would describe it as:
The "unsigned" implies an "int"  So you are defining the first 8 bits of an integer storage.

```
typedef union _STATUS {
BYTE Val;
struct {
    unsigned char BC8 : 1;
    unsigned char BC9 : 1;
    unsigned char BSTALL : 1;
    unsigned char DTSEN : 1; 
    unsigned char INCDIS : 1;
....
} STATUS;
```

When limiting the size to unsigned char, the union is now actually 1 byte.

Comment: As always happens, typing questions makes you think about it more, and look further.  I'd take it down, except it might help someone else with a similar question.

Comment: Your question got upvoted and you've gotten answers to it so I think others _will_ benefit from the question still being visible. You could also accept one of the answers you've gotten.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thx. I was the first upvote to dbush's answer, while composing my own answer.